# language resource bundle empty

Tags: internationalization, xpages

I'm working on internationalizing a website.  I followed the instructions on how to create them but the .properties files are empty.  Any hints about what the problem might be?

thanks
clem

Comment: In order to answer your question we need to know what you have tried have you done "clean project"?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create properties files in the first place. You specify multiple languages in the database properties and Domino Designer will create and populate the properties files for you on save of an XPage or project rebuild. You only need to manually create property files if you want to use them from code with your own messages.